# How to check whether the input is not blank in Ant Input Task?

Tags: java, ant, build

I have a ant script that requires  user inputs. I would like to ensure the correct input type has been entered by the user and if not, prompt them to enter something that is correct.

```
<input message="secure-input:" addproperty="the.password" >
</input>
```

I have to check if the input is blank then i will prompt them to reenter.

Is it possible in ant input task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the conditional clauses allow you at best to [fail](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) the script if some condition is not met. I am imagining that you are gathering some inputs from the user, so failing if the user supplies an empty password might not be the best usability experience, since he would have to input everything all over again...

Furthermore, just testing for an empty string seems like a poor validation, what if the user submits a bunch of spaces?

My (admittedly hackish) suggestion is the following:

```
<target name="askPassword">
    <local name="passwordToValidate"/>
    <input message="secure-input:" addproperty="passwordToValidate"/>

    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[   
            passwordToValidate = project.getProperty("passwordToValidate");

            //You can add more validations here...
            if(passwordToValidate.isEmpty()){
                println("The password cannot be empty.");
                project.executeTarget('askPassword');
            }
        ]]>
    </script>   

    <property name="the.password" value="${passwordToValidate}"/>       
</target>
```

So the highlights:

1. Use the [local task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) to set a local scope for the "passwordToValidate" property (remember that once you set a property on a ant script most tasks don't allow you to rewrite it, so the recursion would be problematic)
2. Test your input with a script (maybe add some more validations)
3. If the test fails, call the target again
4. If the test succeeds, assign the local scoped property to the global scoped one

My 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks Paulp.. I never thought  javascript can be use inside Ant Build... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use condition task to check if input is not empty but you can also use antcontrib to add if/else and show user appropriate message:

```
<if>
    <not>
        <length string="${the.password}" trim="true" when="greater" length="0" />
    </not>
</if>
<then>
    <echo>Your password is empty!</echo>
</then>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) - for `condition` task.